# Starting on Python : Error when doing a tplquad integration

Tags: python, scipy

I'm starting with Python recently, and I've found my first problem when trying to solve the next triple integration:

[image: This is the integration]

So far, I've used the syntax below:

```py
from numpy import cos,pi
from scipy import integrate


f = lambda x, y, z: x**2 * y * (cos * (pi * z) + 2 )

x1,x2 = 0,3
y1,y2 = 0,2
z1,z2 = 0,5

integrate.tplquad(f, x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2 )
```

The main error seems to be the following:

```py
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'numpy.ufunc' and 'float'
```

Please I would appreciate any response from you all :)

Answer (score 0):

In your function definition, you need to delete the `*` after `cos`, because `cos()` is a function, so it goes together with its argument in parentheses.